# Endomorphisms of $\mathbb Z$-modules are the same as those of $\mathbb F_p$-vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, modules

Let $p$ be a prime number. Consider a direct sum of  $n$ copies of the cyclic group of order $p$, written $C_p$: $G=C_p^{\oplus n}$. By a comment in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2863959/finite-groups-isomorphic-to-a-subgroup-of-f) question, given an  $R$-module $M$ and an ideal $I\subset R$, there is a structure of an $R/I$-module on $M$ given by $\overline r x=rx$ ($r\in R,\ x\in M$) provided [$IM=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90283/what-exactly-is-the-structure-im-for-i-an-ideal-and-m-a-module). In our case, $G$ is a $\mathbb Z$-module; after setting $I=(p)$, we see that $IM=0$ is equivalent to $pG=0$, which holds. So there is a $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$
-module structure on $G$. In other words, there is an $\mathbb F_p$-vector space structure on $G$.

As I'm writing this, I came to realize that I don't really understand why is the dimension of this space $n$. (I believe this is so.) *How to justify this?*

Further, any group endomorphism of $G$ is by definition a $\mathbb Z$-module endomorphism of $G$, and it is obvious that any such endomorphism is also an endomorphism as an endo of $\mathbb F_p$-vector space. *Why is the converse true? I.e., why is any endomorphism of $G$ as an $\mathbb F_p$-vector space must be an endomorphism of $G$ as a group ($\mathbb Z$-module)?* First of all, we need to define the structure of a $\mathbb Z$-module on the $\mathbb F_p$-vector space $G$; *how can we do it?*

Comment: Do you believe/understand why $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $n$-diml over the reals?

Comment: Yes I understand.

Comment: It's the same idea.  You have a basis consisting of vectors like $(0, \ldots, 0, 1, 0, \ldots, 0)$ where the single $1$ in the $i$th spot takes care of the $i$th factor of $C_p$ in $G$.  This is your dimension question.  The endo question is different.

Comment: The endo question:  a vector space map is also a group homomorphism (just forget the scaling for a moment).

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that the basis for the $\mathbb Z_p$-module can be chosen the  same as the basis for the $\mathbb Z$-module. I did realize that the $e_i$'s form a basis for $G$ as a $\mathbb Z$-module.

Comment: The $0$s and $1$s mean something different (different group) but not really enough to matter.

Comment: Oh, and be careful:  it doesn't have a "basis" as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module because it's not free.

Comment: Right, in this case $0$ is the identity element of $C_p$ and $1$ is a generator of $C_p$. Indeed, the free $\mathbb Z$-modules are the modules $\mathbb Z^m$. Then I can only say that the $e_i$ form a basis as an $\mathbb F_p$-vector space.

Comment: Right on. Carry on.